# For site security, Is it possible to real-time monitor file & folder's chmod value once they got changed?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, security, ubuntu

Is there methods/solutions like capturing and tracking code injection / malicious file modification event on the php files, so that email alert will be sent to administrator when chmod of default file is changed from 444 to other writable permissions(A prerequisite for file/folder modification) .

Testing Environment 
ubuntu14.04 server
php5 + apache2 
wordpress

Comment: Check out [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) - not quite what you're asking but this is the recommended solution for monitoring your files for unauthorised changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use inotify - the kernels built API for monitoring file system events, 
install inotify-tools, you can then use it like `inotifywait -m -e MODIFY -r /path/to/watch` .. you can get this to call a custom script in which you can do what you want upon detection of file changes.

More info: https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event in `PHP` but you can write script that will calculate hashes of all your files and check them after each execution (eg. via `CRON`).
Same script could check files permissions.